# Magento - Adminhtml - Get id of order just created

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I want to do some post processing on an order, made using **admin** panel.

I have subscribed to the `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_create_save` event, and the correct function of this observer is being invoked.

How can I get the `id` of the order just saved in the `saveAction` in my function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order doesn't appear to save the order in the session anywhere, so this may be tough with the event you've chosen. In fact, the controller action you specified calls _getSession()->clear() to lose all the data from the session.

I would suggest finding a different event to use.

Comment: I already started overriding the controller's save action. Am quite close now. Works on my local/test installation already.